# Does the function vanish?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:I \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $g'(x)$ is never equal to $0$. Here $I=(a,b)$. We also have $\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x)=0$. Is it possible for $g(x)$ to vanish at some point inside the given interval? If not how would I prove that? As the interval is not closed, I can't invoke Rolle's theorem to prove the same. By Darboux's theorem we have that g is strictly monotone. How to rigorously prove this?

Comment: I don't think $g$ will vanish in the interval. $\because \lim_{x \to a^+}g(x) = 0$ and $g'(x) \neq 0$, $g'(x) > 0$ or $g'(x) < 0$. In the first case, $g$ is always positive and in the second case, $g$ is always negative but never zero.

Comment: Can you show it in a more rigorous way? I mean how would I show explicitly that g is always positive or negative

Comment: You could consider a slightly different function $f(x) = g(x) : x \in (a,b)$ and $0 :x = a$. This function is continuous in the interval and differentiable so you can apply LMVT to get $\frac{f(x)}{x-a}=f'(c)$ for some $c \in (a,b)$. Since $f'(c) > 0$ (Just once case) and $x>a$, $f(x) > 0$

Comment: @Aditya Sriram Is it ok to extend the function? Does not that change the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

If we put $g(a):=0$ then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b)$. Assume that $g(c)=0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. By the mean value theorem, applied to $g$ on the interval $[a,c]$, there would then be a $\xi\in (a,c)$ with
$$g'(\xi)={g(c)-g(a)\over c-a}=0\ ,$$
contrary to the assumptions about $g$.